# How to add a license to an user on AZ Powershell?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am using *Azure Powershell* (*AZ* powershell module) on a docker container. I successfully created a new user using *New-AzADUser*. But don't know how to add licenses to the user using AZ cmdlet?

I can't use *Set-AzureADUserLicense/Set-MsolUserLicense* since it is based on *AzureAD/MSOnline* modules and these works only on Windows.

I am trying to find equivalent command in *AZ Powershell* that is compatible with docker/linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there is no equivalent command in `Az`, `Az` was migrated from `AzureRM` module, they are for basically for `ARM` and different from `AzureAD` and `MSOnline` modules.

If you want the `AzureAD` module to be cross-platform, maybe you could post your idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).

Comment: Thanks a lot Joy for the answer. I really appreciated!